# Can single page application javascript not unloading lead to memory issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js, single-page-application

Javascript frameworks like AnguarJs, BackboneJs, Emberjs that use to develop Single Page Applicaitons(SPA's) load lots of js files. Since these files cannot be unloaded can a application go into a situation that cause memory issues because of these js files because SPA's usually doesn't refresh the page.

For an example if application have multiple modules( eg : payroll, attendance,.. of a ERP ) SPA load js files specific to that module to browser when it get loaded. But when navigated to different module without refreshing the page previously loaded js files remain in memory. Imagining application has lots of modules like this is it possible in a certain time these js files cause memory problem ( not enough memory or corruption) ?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that you don't need to use a framework to create a SPA. It is true that at times Angular, React and other frameworks do create bloated code, but they also provide many useful functionality. So depending on the project you may or may not use them.

You can also load your code as modules, and load the modules when needed and unload them when you don't need them. So there is more to SPA's than just using a framework.

Comment: "So there is more to SPA's than just using a framework.'. Very good point.

Answer (score 1):

**Things to remember before developing a Single Page Application**

- Try to use minified versions of JS and css files
- Never use Single page approach if you are developing a large
  application because when all html is renderd in single page then the 
  web application get heavier